# How to display both Account and Contact records using the same VF Page code?

Tags: visualforce

I am using a custom VF page to display duplicate records when a lead conversion occurs.

My class will return to the VF page an error message, with the duplicate records, and the VF Page will display them, and using a radio button, will select if to merge the new contact/account into an existing record, or create a new one.

It works fine if I only have a duplicate contact. But if I have a duplicate account, I get render error (which is ok, as the field: accountid is missing from the account object).

This is my relevant VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Duplicate Records" rendered="{!hasDuplicateResult}">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!duplicateRecords}" var="item">
        <apex:column headerValue="Select to Merge">
            <input type="radio" name="selectRadio" id="radio">
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!setSelectedContactToMerge}" reRender="mergeButton">      
                <apex:param name="selectedMergedContactId" value="{!item['Id']}"/>
                <apex:param name="selectedMergedAccountId" value="{!item['AccountId']}"/>
            </apex:actionSupport>
            </input>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!item['Id']}">{!item['Name']}</apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Owner</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!item['OwnerId']}"/>
        </apex:column>                
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Account</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!item['AccountId']}"/>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Last Modified Date</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputField value="{!item['LastModifiedDate']}"/>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

When getting back duplicate results of accounts, the line:

```
 <apex:outputField value="{!item['AccountId']}"/>
```

Will throw an error. I need it to be:

```
 <apex:outputField value="{!item['Id']}"/>
```

I have a field in my controller, that will set if the results are Account objects or not:

```
isDuplicateAccount = true;
```

But I can't make the display on the VF page conditional to this variable.

Your assistance is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can render correct `outputField` based on `isDuplicateAccount` value

```
<apex:outputField rendered="{! NOT(isDuplicateAccount)}" value="{!item['AccountId']}"/>
<apex:outputField rendered="{! isDuplicateAccount}" value="{!item['Id']}"/>
```

---

or by using [IF logic formula](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm)

```
<apex:outputField value="{!item[IF(isDuplicateAccount, 'Id', 'AccountId')]}"/>
```